# Uso de this en funciones: ¿Cómo funciona el contexto?

Tags: javascript, this

Hay una cosa que no entiendo y es en este caso: el funcionamiento del `this`.

`this` siempre apuntará al objeto que contenga la función y se llamará al `this` desde la función. En el ejemplo que pongo a continuación, mi segundo `this` apunta al objeto que he creado, pero **¿por qué el primer `this` apunta al botón que es un html element?**

`onclick` es un evento, `boton.onclick = function()` ¿Lo tengo que ver como si `onclick` fuera una propiedad que le doy al objeto botón? ¿Debería interpretarlo así? Porque vamos, botón es un html element, me lio con como interpretar esto, ¿O es que el `this` apunta a eventos no solo a objetos ya que el evento es `onclick`?

```js
var boton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  boton.onclick = function(){
    console.log(this);

    let XMLrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XMLrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JSON</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


</head>
<body>
  <button>click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: el this. es como decir el contexto donde se encuentra

Answer (score 21):

### Si quieres una versión muy simplificada:

`this` apunta al contexto. En los manejadores de eventos, `this` es el elemento que ha recibido el evento (el botón, el div, el link...). Si llamas a una función como si fuese un método, `this` es el objeto. Pero que la función sea declarada como un método no asegura que sea llamada como tal.

### Si quieres una versión más larga y "didáctica", con ejemplos:

El comportamiento de `this` es un poco especial en Javascript: Indica el contexto en el que está ejecutando el código. Si estás en el contexto global (no estás dentro de ninguna función), `this` es `window`. Si llamas a una función simplemente usando el nombre de la misma, el contexto se mantiene:

```js
console.log(this===window);
function test() {
  console.log(this===window);
  if (this!==window) {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

test();
```

Pero en modo estricto, el contexto al llamar una función usando su nombre es `undefined`:

```js
'use strict';

console.log(this===window);
    
function test() {
  console.log(this===window);
  if (this!==window) {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

test();
```

Pero si esa función es un atributo de un objeto, entonces `this` pasa a ser ese objeto:

```js
function test() {
  console.log('Es window?:' + (this===window));
  if (this!==window) {
    console.log('Es obj?:' + (this===obj));
  }
}

console.log('Modo no estricto');

var obj={ 
  prueba: 'hola'
}

test();

console.log('Como método');

obj.metodo=test;

obj.metodo();
```

Entonces, cuando definimos una función callback podemos tener problemas si no sabemos cuál es el contexto donde se ejecuta la función:

```js
class Contador {

  constructor() {
    this.count=0;
  }
  
  incrementar() {
    this.count++;
  }
}

let c= new Contador()
c.incrementar();
console.log(c.count)

let funcionInc=c.incrementar;

//falla porque el contexto no es un objeto Contador
funcionInc();
```

Imagina que tenemos un evento que queremos tratar con nuestro objeto contador:

```js
class Contador {

  constructor() {
    this.count=0;
  }
  
  incrementar() {
    if (this.count !== undefined) {
      this.count++;
    } else {
      console.log('No hay count para incrementar!');
    }
  }
}

let c= new Contador();

$('button').on('click',c.incrementar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Soluciones a este problema hay varias:

Una es "envolver" la ejecución con otra función:

```js
class Contador {

  constructor() {
    this.count=0;
  }
  
  incrementar() {
    if (this.count !== undefined) {
      this.count++;
      console.log(this.count);
    } else {
      console.log('No hay count para incrementar!');
    }
  }
}

let c= new Contador();

$('button').on('click',function () {c.incrementar();});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Y otra solución es usar `bind()` (literalmente *atar*): permite fijar un contexto a una función, creando una nueva función que se comporta exactamente igual pero que siempre tiene el contexto que le hemos definido:

```js
class Contador {

  constructor() {
    this.count=0;
  }
  
  incrementar() {
    if (this.count !== undefined) {
      this.count++;
      console.log(this.count);
    } else {
      console.log('No hay count para incrementar!');
    }
  }
}

let c= new Contador();
//con bind fijamos el contexto
let funcion=c.incrementar.bind(c);

$('button').on('click',funcion);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Otra solución es usar una función flecha. Las funciones flecha son un poco especiales, porque asignan el contexto en el momento en el que se definen, no cuando se ejecutan:

```js
class Contador {

  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    
  }
  
  incrementar = () => { 
    this.count++;
    console.log(this.count);  
  }
}

let c = new Contador();

//no hace falta bind, el contexto se fijó al declarar la función
$('button').on('click',c.incrementar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 8):

**MDN** define [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) como:

> Una **propiedad** que devuelve el manejador del evento click del elemento actual.

El valor que recibe `this` depende de la forma en la cual se ejecuta/llama la función, veamos algunos ejemplos

**Ejemplo 1**

```js
function saludar(){
    console.log(this)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="saludar()">Saludar</button>
```

Como puedes ver en este ejemplo el `this` en este caso hace referencia al `window`

**Ejemplo 2**

```js
function saludar(elemento){
    console.log(elemento)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="saludar(this)">Saludar</button>
```

De esta forma si yo quisiera que `this` hiciera referencia al elemento que ejecuta el evento tendría que mandarlo como parámetro en la función que es disparada por el evento.

**Ejemplo 3**

```js
var boton = document.querySelector('button');

boton.onclick = function(){
    console.log(this)
}

boton.addEventListener('mouseenter', saludar);

function saludar(){
    console.log(this)
}
```

```html
<button>Saludar</button>
```

En cualquiera de estos dos casos `this` hace referencia directa al elemento que dispara el evento.

Answer (score 5):

Buenas espero te ayude

### this

> La función de la palabra clave this se comporta un poco diferente en Javascript en comparación con otros lenguajes. Además tiene algunas diferencias entre el modo estricto y el modo no estricto.
>
> En general, el valor de this está determinado por cómo se llama a la función. No puede ser establecida por una asignación en tiempo de ejecución, y esto puede ser diferente cada vez que la función es llamada. ES5 introdujo el método bind() para establecer el valor de la función this independientemente de como es llamada.

En este caso `this` va a referenciar a:

```
<button type="button" name="button">Boton</button>
```

Que seria el objeto que ejecuta el evento espero te ayude saludos.

```js
  var boton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  boton.onclick = function(){
    console.log("El this es = ",this);

    let XMLrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XMLrequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button">Boton</button>
```

### Ejemplos

Contexto global
En el contexto de ejecución global (fuera de cualquier función), this se refiere al objeto global, ya sea en modo estricto o no.

```js
console.log(this.document === document); // true

// En los navegadores web, el objeto window también es un objeto global:
console.log(this === window); // true

this.a = 37;
console.log(window.a); // 37
```

### Contexto de la función

Dentro de una función, el valor de this depende de cómo la función es llamada.

```
function f1(){
  return this;
}

 f1() === window; // objeto global
```

En este caso, el valor de `this` no está establecido por la llamada. Dado que el código no está en modo estricto, el valor de `this` debe ser siempre un objeto por lo que por defecto es el objeto global.

```
function f2(){
  "use strict"; // consultar modo estricto
  return this;
}

 f2() === undefined;
```

> Fuente: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this)

Answer (score 3):

`onclick` no es un evento, es un método que será llamado en caso de que ocurra el evento. Y efectivamente ese método pertenece al objeto `boton`.

Comment: no sabia que boton es un objeto, todo son objeto entonces? Boton es un html element en un principio HASTA QUE al adjuntarle una funcion, onclick sera un metodo y boton su objeto?

Comment: En Javascript casi todo son objetos.

Comment: `boton` es una instancia (objeto) de la clase `HTMLElement` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)