# Rescatar el valor de un booleano

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy trabajando en angular 9 y en mi TS. Tengo una variable boolena (add) que inicia en falso y tengo una función click que agrega uno por uno los detalles del producto, al verificarse que se dio click a todos los detalles que existan, la variable **add** pasa a ser **verdadera**, que permitiría ejecutar la función **addCart** pero no se como invocar la respuesta de esta variable fuera del ciclo for. Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

```
    //product.ts

export class ProductLeftComponent implements OnInit {

render:boolean = true;

add:boolean = false;


 callback(){

  if(this.render){

      let arrayDetail = [];

      let qtyDetail = JSON.parse($(".ps-product__variations").attr("specification"));
      let qty = qtyDetail.length;

      /* Agrego detalles del producto*/
      $(document).on("click", ".details", function(){
        
        //Capturo el nombre del detalle
        let detailType = $(this).attr("detailType");         

        
        if (arrayDetail.indexOf(detailType) === -1) arrayDetail.push(detailType);

        for(let i = 0; i < arrayDetail.length; i++){

          if(qty === arrayDetail.length){

            this.add = true; // esta respuesta necesito que salga
          }
          
        }
       
       }


  }

 }

addCart(product){

    if(this.add === true){

      
      this.cartProductsService.addCart(product);

    }else{

      Sweetalert.fnc("info", "DEBES SELECCIONAR TODOS LOS DETALLES DE ESTE PRODUCTO", null);
      return;
    }

  }


}
```

Comment: @Lobos.. la variable this.add = true; que esta dentro del siclo for, necesito que la reconozca addCart(product)

Comment: @Lobos, no lo hace. Alguna idea de como podría this.add = true; salir fuera del $(document).on("click") ??

Comment: @Lobos según la consola si.

Comment: @Lobos.. un producto tiene 4 detalles, sino selecciono ningún detalle, la variable add es falsa, y el botón que tengo la función addCart no me permitirá agregar el producto al carrito, si selecciono 1, 2 o 3 detalles sigue siendo falsa, por ello cuando alcanza la cantidad total de detalles seleccionados, add es verdadero y ahí debería poder dar al botón agregar producto. Pero this.add = true; al estar dentro $(document).on("click") addCart() no detecta el cambio

Comment: Una variable no *da una respuesta*, es estática, sólo almacena una dirección de memoria. Las funciones, por otro lado si que pueden *dar respuesta*. Por lo que entiendo, necesitas añadir al carrito (¿automáticamente?) cuando el valor de `add` sea verdadero. Para esto tal vez necesites trabajar con eventos, de tal forma que suscribas tu función de añadir al carrito al evento disparado cuando `add` se haga verdadero. Eso implica crear algún objeto emisor de eventos que reciba los posibles cambios realizados en la UI y despache el evento adecuado cuando `add` sea verdadero. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras no, no es automático, se debe dar click a un botón que tengo en la vista para agregar el producto al carrito. pero dentro de lo que dices, si tienes toda la razón. Ahora estaba pensando algo similar, veía que el callback se ejecuta tomando todos los valores por defecto, y como la variable es estática, y aunque se convirtiera en verdadera y que la sacara fuera del ciclo for, aun así  no tendría resultados. Estaba ya pensando ver con un observable "rxjs" pero implicaría crear un servicio y no creo sea lo mas conveniente, sabes como podría incluir un objeto emisor de eventos?

Comment: Otra forma consiste en llamar a tu función de añadir al carrito justo después que estableces el valor de `add`, fuera de tu ciclo `for`. Así, con cada cambio en la UI, se llamará a la función de añadir al carrito, pero esto puede llegar a ser molesto. Imagina que cada vez que hago un cambio me sale una alerta indicandome que *debo llenar todos los detalles*. Muy mal diseño, pero es un punto de partida. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras los click de la selección de los detalles lo hago dentro del TS con jQuery y no se conecta con el botón de enviar al carrito que esta en la vista. Esto lo hice considerando que no todos los productos traen detalles a seleccionar.

Comment: Ese es otro asunto ¿Porqué combinar JQuery y Angular? Todo el manejo del DOM deberías delegarlo a Angular, no a JQuery. Estás desaprovechando las características de Angular. Recuerda que los componentes pueden manejar algo llamado [Event binding](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding). Mi recomendación es que evites usar JQuery, ya que Angular hará todo lo que necesites sin tener que acudir a JQuery. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras si te encuentro toda la razón, esta es una web que ha sido creada completa en jQuery en sus inicios, ahora la estoy modificando en angular pero todavía no soy experta en este framework, por ahora debo dejar este pequeño trozo de código funcional, ya después con tiempo lo modificare para eliminar completamente jQuery.

Comment: Vamos a lo básico: ¿Dónde se llama addCart? ¿Tienes una llamada desde la plantilla/template?

Comment: @PabloLozano si, en la vista tengo una etiqueta ancor con el que agrego productos al carrito. (click)="addCart(product)"

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tienes un problema de contexto:

```
callback(){
   //aquí "this" es el componente
  if(this.render){
      let arrayDetail = [];
      let qtyDetail = JSON.parse($(".ps-product__variations").attr("specification"));
      let qty = qtyDetail.length;
      /* Agrego detalles del producto*/
      $(document).on("click", ".details", function(){
         //aquí "this" es el elemento sobre el que has clickado
         ...
      });
  }
}
```

Una solución sería usar una función flecha para que `this` fuese el componente de Angular, pero me he dado cuenta de que también usas this cuando te refieres al elemento:

```
    //Capturo el nombre del detalle
    let detailType = $(this).attr("detailType");
```

La solución rápida sería guardar el contexto (el valor de `this`) previo:

```
callback(){
   //aquí "this" es el componente
  if(this.render){
      let arrayDetail = [];
      let qtyDetail = JSON.parse($(".ps-product__variations").attr("specification"));
      let qty = qtyDetail.length;
      /* Agrego detalles del producto*/
      const ngThis = this; //this es el componente
      $(document).on("click", ".details", function(){
         //aquí "this" es el elemento sobre el que has clickado
         //pero ngThis guarda el contexto del componente
         ...
         ngThis.add = true;
      });
  }
}
```

La solución más elegante sería eliminar jQuery de tu código, añadiendo un `(click)="onClickDetails(detailType)"` a tu elemento en la plantilla y gestionando el click con Angular.

Comment: Más información sobre el contexto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126034/donde-apunta-el-this-en-este-primer-ejemplo

Comment: He editado un poco la respuesta para intentar aclararlo. Por otro lado, he visto tu preguntas previas y te recomiendo que, si hay una respuesta que te soluciona el problema planteado, la *aceptes* activando el "check" que hay al lado. Así la pregunta queda marcada como respondida y tanto el que pregunta como el que responde se llevan una pequeña recompensa extra (a menos que la respuesta sea también tuya, pero aún así es mejor marcarla

Comment: uyyy uyyy muchas gracias Pablo, funciona de forma perfecta tu ayuda. Es increíble que era algo tan simple. Te amo.!! gracias.