# ¿Cómo llamo a una función desde otra con "this" para que no me dé el error "this.X is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, this

Estoy creando unas funciones de forma genérica, que luego llamaré según algunos parámetros. Las funciones las guardo juntas en algo así como `misFunciones`. Después en una parte de mi código recibo un parámetro que me indica qué función llamar.

Si la función a llamar no interactúa con el resto, todo va bien. Ahora, si interactúa con otras vía `this`, falla con el error:

> this.b is not a function

Más o menos sería así:

```js
var misFunciones = {
    b() {
        console.log('bbb')
    },
    c() {
        this.b();
        console.log('ccc')
    }
};

v = misFunciones.c;
v()
```

Me doy cuenta que si modifico `this.b()` por `misFunciones.b()`, sí funciona. Ahora, no sé si es la solución definitiva o debería usar otro tipo de aproximación.

He estado leyendo en JavaScript MDN las páginas [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) y [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), que me han dado de la idea de usar la referencia absoluta (`misFunciones.b()` en lugar de `this.b()`), pero no sé hay alguna otra aproximación más estándar y recomendable.

En definitiva: ¿cómo hago para referenciar una función desde otra, para que luego pueda llamarla externamente y de forma dinámica?

Comment: Muy relacionada, ¿quizá duplicada? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126034/donde-apunta-el-this-en-este-primer-ejemplo/. No voto cerrar porque no sé si es lo que estás buscando y tengo el "martillo de oro". Puedes marcarla como duplicada tú mismo si lo consideras así

Comment: Es excelente la información que indicas, @PabloLozano. Mil gracias. No me deja votar para cerrar (agoté los votos diarios), dale con tu martillo sin pudor. ¿Quizá valdría la pena retitular la pregunta que enlazas para que sea más encontrable? No supe verla yo al buscar antes de enviari esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias opciones para definir el contexto en el que se llama a una función. En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/126104/83) hay una descripción general de qué es `this` y cómo se define según como se llama o declara una función, así que simplemente enumeraré opciones, usando tu código como ejemplo:

```js
const misFunciones = {
    b() {
        console.log('bbb')
    },
    c(param) {
        this.b();
        console.log(param)
    }
};

// uso bind para definir el contexto
const v1 = misFunciones.c.bind(misFunciones);
v1('v1');

// encapsulo la llamada en una función. Al hacer la llamada como 
// método, se mantiene el contexto como "mis Funciones
const v2 = (p) => misFunciones.c(p);
v2('v2');

// ejecuto la función usando apply, donde defino el contexto
const v3 = misFunciones.c;
v3.apply(misFunciones,['v3']);
```

Comment: Trabajando con Vuejs la versión que me funcionó mejor fue la 3.ª, la de usar apply.