# Función Flecha y función normal

Tags: javascript, funciones, onclick

Tengo varios *DIVs* con la misma clase e hice el siguiente código para sacar el texto con el evento `onclick`. Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué la primera no funciona y la segunda sí?

¿Tiene que ver el tipo de funcion?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < opc.length; i++) {
  //Este no me funciona
  opc[i].onclick = () => {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  };

  //Este si me funciona
  opc[i].onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  };
}
```

Comment: El funcionamiento de `this` no es el mismo en las funciones flecha, que en las funciones convencionales. Te invito a leer el [siguiente artículo](https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/#1-this-value) -en inglés- en el que podrías encontrar más detalles y diferencias entre las funciones convencionales y las funciones flecha.

Comment: @mgEder quizás te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/363155/explicaci%c3%b3n-de-funciones-flecha-en-javascript/363175#363175), especialmente el punto 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una serie de reglas que nos pueden ayudar a saber cuál es el contexto de ejecución vinculado a una función (`this` binding).

#### This binding en Event handlers

Cuando se declara una función anónima con la sintáxis `function`, el `this` vinculado es:

- El objeto que llama a la función (En este caso el `Div` `opc[i]`)

Esto funciona:

```
//Este si me funciona
opc[i].onclick = function(){
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

Cuando se declara una función anónima con la sintáxis `arrow`, el `this` vinculado puede ser:

- Strict Mode: `undefined`
- No Strict Mode : El objeto Global `Window`

Esto no funciona:

```
//Este no me funciona
opc[i].onclick = ()=>{
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

---

#### Observando las reglas para arrow function

Dicho lo anterior, para el caso de la sintáxis `arrow`, supongamos que se esta trabajando en `Strict Mode`, al dar click a alguno de los `div's`, Javascript regresará:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.innerHTML')

Porque, de acuerdo con las reglas listadas anteriormente, el valor de `this` de la función `arrow` del `onclick` tiene vinculado `undefined`; entonces `undefined.innerHTML` no es un objeto.

Después, supongamos que se está trabajando en `Non Strict Mode`, al dar click a alguno de los `div's`, Javascript regresará:

> undefined

Porque, de acuerdo con las reglas listadas anteriormente, el valor de `this` de la función `arrow` del `onclick` tiene vinculado el objeto global `Window`.

Además de que `opc[i]` no es parte del objeto global `Window`, Javascript asigna valor `undefined` a propiedades no definidas, por eso se tiene `undefined` para `this.innerHTML`, pues `innerHTML` no está definída en el objeto global `Window`.

---

#### Notas de campo

- Es un tema complicado, yo sugiero que trates de que tenga sentido conforme encuentres casos de uso, como este.
- Las reglas pueden cambiar dependiendo el Javascript hosting enviroment (Browser, node.js etc...)
- Puede haber problemas de referencias al usar funciones anónimas en Event handlers, sobre todo cuando se trata de remover el Event handler.

[Uso de this en Event Handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#as_a_dom_event_handler)

[Uso de This en funciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126034/uso-de-this-en-funciones-c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-contexto/126104#126104)

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda